# Where to ask a question about analysis and understanding of a propietary file format related to a fingerprint

Tags: support, site-recommendation

There is a quite [difficult question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/109153/95471) I am looking answer for. Although it has something to do with security, it seems to be off-topic on Security Stack Exchange and I suppose it will be off-topic on a Cryptography Stack Exchange as well.

Is there any site on the Stack Exchange network where this question would be suitable?

Comment: Well, it seems your question is more programming related. Eventually Programmers SE could fit, Stack Overflow less IMHO. If the fingerprint image format is really proprietary, you might need to refer to the manufacturer actually as it was mentioned in a comment.

Comment: It's not the image, but the representation of finger characteristics. If the finger is represented as a list of minutiae, then I need to understand how this list is packed to the binary data. Otherwise I need to find out how a finger is represented by it. What about manufacturer: since I already tried to get in contact with it unsuccessfully, I think there is a very little hope to get some informations that way.

Comment: Hmm, I had a look at that documentation you linked, and all I can say is that they call it an _image_.

Comment: What I am referring to is declared as *character*. A *character file buffer* is defined in section 4.2.2. It is referenced in several instructions: Img2Tz (section 6.2.4) and the followings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the [help center](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for [ReverseEngineering.SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) and see if it might be suitable there.  From my reading, it sounds like your question might be acceptable there, if you are asking how to reverse engineer the system, but I'm not a regular on that site and I don't know for sure.  I recommend that you ask a more specific question than "Is there any hope to understand that format...?"

Fair warning: There's no guarantee that any particular question will have a home on some Stack Exchange site.  Some questions aren't suitable on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal - RE really seems to be suitable for my question better - and also for the warning.